# Should I be using the Combination interpretation or the Permutation interpretation?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, combinatorics

**Question:** *A family has three children but you don’t know their sexes. If at least two are boys, what’s the probability one child is a girl (assuming that all outcomes are equally likely)?*

**My Answers**

Define the events $E:="at\ least\ two\ boys"$, $F:="exactly\ one\ girl"$

***Combination interpretation:*** Here $E=\{\mbox{BBB, BBG}\}$ (i.e. "3 boys" or "2 boys and 1 girl"). Note the combinations $\mbox{\{BBG\}}=\mbox{\{BGB\}}=\mbox{\{GBB\}}$ (are equivalent) as we are ignoring order. Thus, there is only one combination of this where there is $"at\ least\ two\ boys\ AND\ one\ girl"=E \cap F=\mbox{\{BBG\}}$, hence

$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\mathbb{P}(F|E) & = \frac{\mathbb{P}(E \cap F)}{\mathbb{P}(E)} \\
& = \frac{|E\cap F|}{|E|}\\
& = \frac{1}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

[This seems somewhat intuitive as once we know the sexes of 2 of the children, we only care about the sex of the last child (which is equally likely of being a boy or girl by assumption).]

***Permutation interpretation:*** Since order now matters, we have $E=\{\mbox{BBB, BBG, BGB, GBB}\}$ and $E \cap F=\mbox{\{BBG,BGB,GBB\}}$, hence

$$\mathbb{P}(F|E) = \frac{3}{4}$$

**My Question: Should I be using the Combination interpretation or the Permutation interpretation?**

I feel regardless of which interpretation I use, the answer should be the same - but it isn't??? Is my logic correct, or have I gone wrong somewhere (am I missing possible outcomes within one of the interpretations)?

Comment: @Xi'an - I don't fill this is a duplicate, in particular the question marked as duplicate does not specify *why* they consider BG to be different from GB? As far as I can tell, the question doesn't explicitly say that the ordering of children matters?

Comment: Saying that combinations are "equivalent" does not magically change their associated probabilities, you're just lumping them into one group. In the combinations interpretation, you are left with two "equivalent" events: $BBB$ and $BBG$, and $P(BBB)=1/8$ whereas $P(BBG)=P(\{BBG\})+P(\{BGB\})+P(\{GBB\})$, where the events on the r.h.s are everything equivalent to the unordered pair $BBG$

Comment: The self-study question that the OP is trying to answer is essentially similar to the one in the duplicate ... however, I think that what the OP is *asking to have explained* is a sufficiently different point to justify a separate thread.